# Benchmarking efficient inversion counting algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, unit-testing, benchmarking

Given an array \$A = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)\$, the number of ***inversions*** in \$A\$ is the number of index pairs \$i,j\$ (\$i < j\$) such that \$a_i > a_j\$. We can find the number of inversions in an array by running it through a slightly modified mergesort, which runs in \$\Theta(n \log n)\$. Even better, we can deploy a *natural* mergesort which runs in \$\Theta(n \log m)\$ time where \$m\$ is the number of runs in the input array. As a reminder, a *run* is a contiguous subsequence that is ascending. Needless to say, \$m \leq n\$. Without further ado, let's proceed to code:

**BruteForceInversionCounter.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utils.NATURAL_ORDER;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utils.checkIndices;

/**
 * This class implements a brute force inversion counting algorithm that runs in
 * quadratic time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public final class BruteForceInversionCounter {

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, 
                                int fromIndex,
                                int toIndex, 
                                Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
        checkIndices(array.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
        int inversions = 0;

        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < toIndex; ++j) {
                if (comparator.compare(array[i], array[j]) > 0) {
                    inversions++;
                }
            }
        }

        return inversions;
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return count(array, fromIndex, toIndex, NATURAL_ORDER);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        return count(array, 0, array.length, comparator);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array) {
        return count(array, NATURAL_ORDER);
    }

    private BruteForceInversionCounter() {}
}
```

**MergesortInversionCounter.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utils.NATURAL_ORDER;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utils.checkIndices;

/**
 * This class implements a modification of merge sort that sorts an input array 
 * range and returns the number of inversions in the input range.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public final class MergesortInversionCounter {


    public static <T> int count(T[] array, 
                                int fromIndex, 
                                int toIndex, 
                                Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        checkIndices(array.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
        int rangeLength = toIndex - fromIndex;

        if (rangeLength < 2) {
            return 0;
        }

        T[] aux = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
        return count(aux, array, 0, fromIndex, rangeLength, comparator);
    }

    private static <T> int count(T[] sourceArray,
                                 T[] targetArray,
                                 int sourceOffset,
                                 int targetOffset,
                                 int rangeLength,
                                 Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        if (rangeLength < 2) {
            return 0;
        }

        int halfRangeLength = rangeLength >>> 1;
        int inversions = count(targetArray,
                               sourceArray,
                               targetOffset,
                               sourceOffset,
                               halfRangeLength,
                               comparator);

        inversions += count(targetArray,
                            sourceArray,
                            targetOffset + halfRangeLength,
                            sourceOffset + halfRangeLength,
                            rangeLength - halfRangeLength,
                            comparator);

        return inversions + merge(sourceArray,
                                  targetArray,
                                  sourceOffset,
                                  targetOffset,
                                  halfRangeLength,
                                  rangeLength - halfRangeLength,
                                  comparator);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return count(array, fromIndex, toIndex, NATURAL_ORDER);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        return count(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array) {
        return count(array, NATURAL_ORDER);
    }

    private static <T> int merge(T[] sourceArray,
                                 T[] targetArray,
                                 int sourceOffset,
                                 int targetOffset,
                                 int leftRunLength,
                                 int rightRunLength,
                                 Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        int inversions       = 0;
        int leftRunIndex     = sourceOffset;
        int leftRunEndIndex  = sourceOffset + leftRunLength;
        int rightRunIndex    = sourceOffset + leftRunLength;
        int rightRunEndIndex = rightRunIndex + rightRunLength;
        int targetIndex      = targetOffset;

        while (leftRunIndex < leftRunEndIndex 
                && rightRunIndex < rightRunEndIndex) {
            if (comparator.compare(sourceArray[rightRunIndex], 
                                   sourceArray[leftRunIndex]) < 0) {
                inversions += leftRunEndIndex - leftRunIndex;
                targetArray[targetIndex++] = sourceArray[rightRunIndex++];
            } else {
                targetArray[targetIndex++] = sourceArray[leftRunIndex++];
            }
        }

        System.arraycopy(sourceArray, 
                         leftRunIndex, 
                         targetArray,
                         targetIndex, 
                         leftRunEndIndex - leftRunIndex);
        System.arraycopy(sourceArray,
                         rightRunIndex,
                         targetArray, 
                         targetIndex, 
                         rightRunEndIndex - rightRunIndex);
        return inversions;
    }

    private MergesortInversionCounter() {}
}
```

**NaturalMergesortInversionCounter.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utils.NATURAL_ORDER;
import static net.coderodde.util.Utils.checkIndices;

/**
 * This class implements a modification of the natural mergesort that counts 
 * inversion in the input array range.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public final class NaturalMergesortInversionCounter {

    public static <T> int count(T[] array,
                                int fromIndex,
                                int toIndex) {
        return count(array, fromIndex, toIndex, NATURAL_ORDER);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        return count(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        return count(array, 0, array.length, comparator);
    }

    public static <T> int count(T[] array, 
                                int fromIndex, 
                                int toIndex, 
                                Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array);
        Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
        checkIndices(array.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
        int rangeLength = toIndex - fromIndex;

        if (rangeLength < 2) {
            return 0;
        }

        RunLengthQueue runLengthQueue = 
                buildRunLengthQueue(array, 
                                    fromIndex, 
                                    toIndex, 
                                    comparator);

        T[] bufferArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
        T[] sourceArray;
        T[] targetArray;
        int sourceOffset;
        int targetOffset;
        int mergePasses = getNumberOfMergePasses(runLengthQueue.size());

        if ((mergePasses & 1) == 1) {
            // Odd amount of merge passes over the entire input array range.
            // Set the buffer array as the source array so that the sorted 
            // result ends in in the input array.
            sourceArray = bufferArray;
            targetArray = array;
            sourceOffset = 0;
            targetOffset = fromIndex;
        } else {
            sourceArray = array;
            targetArray = bufferArray;
            sourceOffset = fromIndex;
            targetOffset = 0;
        }

        int runsLeftInCurrentMergePass = runLengthQueue.size();
        int offset = 0;
        int inversions = 0;

        // While there are runs to merge, iterate:
        while (runLengthQueue.size() > 1) {
            int leftRunLength  = runLengthQueue.dequeue();
            int rightRunLength = runLengthQueue.dequeue();

            inversions += merge(sourceArray,
                                targetArray,
                                sourceOffset + offset,
                                targetOffset + offset,
                                leftRunLength,
                                rightRunLength,
                                comparator);

            runLengthQueue.enqueue(leftRunLength + rightRunLength);
            runsLeftInCurrentMergePass -= 2;
            offset += leftRunLength + rightRunLength;

            switch (runsLeftInCurrentMergePass) {
                case 1:
                    int lastRunLength = runLengthQueue.dequeue();
                    // In the target array, this 'unmarried' run might be
                    // in the form of two unmerged runs.
                    System.arraycopy(sourceArray,
                                     sourceOffset + offset, 
                                     targetArray,
                                     targetOffset + offset,
                                     lastRunLength);
                    runLengthQueue.enqueue(lastRunLength);
                    // FALL THROUGH!

                case 0:
                    runsLeftInCurrentMergePass = runLengthQueue.size();
                    offset = 0;

                    T[] tmpArray = sourceArray;
                    sourceArray = targetArray;
                    targetArray = tmpArray;

                    int tmpOffset = sourceOffset;
                    sourceOffset = targetOffset;
                    targetOffset = tmpOffset;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return inversions;
    }

    static <T> RunLengthQueue 
    buildRunLengthQueue(T[] inputArray, 
                        int fromIndex,
                        int toIndex,
                        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        int last = toIndex - 1;
        int left = fromIndex;
        int right = left + 1;
        RunLengthQueue runLengthQueue =
                new RunLengthQueue(toIndex - fromIndex);
        while (left < last) {
            int head = left;

            while (left < last 
                    && comparator.compare(inputArray[left],
                                          inputArray[right]) <= 0) {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            ++left;
            ++right;

            runLengthQueue.enqueue(left - head);
        }

        if (left == last) {
            runLengthQueue.enqueue(1);
        }

        return runLengthQueue;
    }

    /**
     * This static inner class implements a simple queue of integers used to 
     * represent the run sequence in the array to sort.
     */
    private static final class RunLengthQueue {

        /**
         * The minimum capacity of the storage array.
         */
        private static final int MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 256;

        /**
         * Stores the run lengths.
         */
        private final int[] storage;

        /**
         * The index of the array component that will be dequeued next.
         */
        private int head;

        /**
         * The index of the array component to which the next run length will
         * be set.
         */
        private int tail;

        /**
         * The current number of run lengths stored in this queue.
         */
        private int size;

        /**
         * A bit mask used for simpler modulo calculation (at least at the level
         * of hardware).
         */
        private final int mask;

        /**
         * Creates a run length queue large enough to hold maximum of 
         * {@code capacity} elements.
         * 
         * @param capacity the requested capacity, may be increased in the 
         *                 constructor.
         */
        RunLengthQueue(int capacity) {
            capacity = ceilPowerOfTwo(Math.max(capacity, MINIMUM_CAPACITY));
            this.mask = capacity - 1;
            this.storage = new int[capacity];
        }

        /**
         * Enqueues a given run length to the tail of this queue.
         * 
         * @param runLength the run length to enqueue.
         */
        void enqueue(int runLength) {
            storage[tail] = runLength;
            tail = (tail + 1) & mask;
            size++;
        }

        /**
         * Dequeues the run length from the head of this queue.
         * 
         * @return the run length stored in the head of this queue.
         */
        int dequeue() {
            int ret = storage[head];
            head = (head + 1) & mask;
            size--;
            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of run lengths stored in this queue.
         * 
         * @return the number of run lengths.
         */
        int size() {
            return size;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a smallest power of two no less than {@code number}.
         * 
         * @param number the number to ceil.
         * @return a smallest power of two no less than {@code number}.
         */
        private static int ceilPowerOfTwo(int number) {
            int ret = Integer.highestOneBit(number);
            return ret != number ? (ret << 1) : ret;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes the required number of merge passes needed to sort an input
     * array range containing {@code runs} runs.
     * 
     * @param runs the number of runs in the input array range.
     * @return the number of required merge passes.
     */
    private static int getNumberOfMergePasses(int runs) {
        return 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(runs - 1);
    }

    private static <T> int merge(T[] sourceArray,
                                 T[] targetArray,
                                 int sourceOffset,
                                 int targetOffset,
                                 int leftRunLength,
                                 int rightRunLength,
                                 Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        int leftRunIndex = sourceOffset;
        int rightRunIndex = leftRunIndex + leftRunLength;
        int leftRunEndIndex = rightRunIndex;
        int rightRunEndIndex = rightRunIndex + rightRunLength;
        int targetIndex = targetOffset;
        int inversions = 0;

        while (leftRunIndex != leftRunEndIndex 
                && rightRunIndex != rightRunEndIndex) {
            if (comparator.compare(sourceArray[rightRunIndex],
                                   sourceArray[leftRunIndex]) <0) {
                inversions += leftRunEndIndex - leftRunIndex;
                targetArray[targetIndex++] = sourceArray[rightRunIndex++];
            } else {
                targetArray[targetIndex++] = sourceArray[leftRunIndex++];
            }
        }

        System.arraycopy(sourceArray,
                         leftRunIndex,
                         targetArray,
                         targetIndex,
                         leftRunEndIndex - leftRunIndex);

        System.arraycopy(sourceArray, 
                         rightRunIndex,
                         targetArray,
                         targetIndex,
                         rightRunEndIndex - rightRunIndex);

        return inversions;
    }

    private NaturalMergesortInversionCounter() {}
}
```

**Utils.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * This class contains generic facilities.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public final class Utils {

    public static final Comparator NATURAL_ORDER = new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);    
        }
    };

    public static void checkIndices(int arrayLength,
                                    int fromIndex, 
                                    int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") < 0");
        }

        if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "toIndex(" + toIndex + ") > " + 
                    "arrayLength(" + arrayLength + ")");
        }

        if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

**AbstractInversionCounterTest.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * This abstract test class implements all the actual unit tests.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public abstract class AbstractInversionCounterTest {

    private static final int TEST_ITERATIONS = 100;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_ARRAY_LENGTH = 1000;

    protected final InversionCounter<Integer> inversionCounter;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public AbstractInversionCounterTest(
            InversionCounter<Integer> inversionCounter) {
        this.inversionCounter = inversionCounter;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < TEST_ITERATIONS; iteration++) {
            int length = random.nextInt(MAXIMUM_ARRAY_LENGTH + 1);
            int fromIndex = random.nextInt(Math.max(1, length / 10));
            int toIndex = 
                    length - random.nextInt(
                            Math.max(1, (length - fromIndex) / 10));

            Integer[] array1 = getRandomIntegerArray(length,
                                                     -length / 2 - 10,
                                                     +length / 2 + 10,
                                                     random);
            Integer[] array2 = array1.clone();

            assertEquals(BruteForceInversionCounter.count(array1, 
                                                          fromIndex, 
                                                          toIndex, 
                                                          Integer::compareTo),
                         inversionCounter.count(array2, 
                                                fromIndex, 
                                                toIndex, 
                                                Integer::compareTo));
            Arrays.sort(array1, fromIndex, toIndex);
            assertTrue(Arrays.equals(array1, array2));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a random integer array.
     * 
     * @param length   the desired length of the array.
     * @param minValue the minimum integer value.
     * @param maxValue the maximum integer value.
     * @param random   the random number generator.
     * @return a randomly generated integer array.
     */
    private Integer[] getRandomIntegerArray(int length,
                                            int minValue,
                                            int maxValue,
                                            Random random) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            array[i] = randomValue(minValue, maxValue, random);
        }

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random integer value from the range {@code minValue,
     * minValue + 1, ..., maxValue - 1, maxValue}, according to the uniform 
     * distribution.
     * 
     * @param minValue the minimum integer value.
     * @param maxValue the maximum integer value.
     * @param random   the random number generator.
     * @return a random integer value within the range.
     */
    private Integer randomValue(int minValue, int maxValue, Random random) {
        return minValue + random.nextInt(maxValue - minValue + 1);
    }
}
```

**InversionCounter.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Defines the most specific API for inversion counting algorithms.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 * @param <T> the array component type.
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface InversionCounter<T> {

    public int count(T[] array, 
                     int fromIndex,
                     int toIndex, 
                     Comparator<? super T> comparator);
}
```

**MergesortInversionCounterTest.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

/**
 * This unit test tests the correctness of the mergesort-based inversion 
 * counter.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public class MergesortInversionCounterTest 
        extends AbstractInversionCounterTest {

    public MergesortInversionCounterTest() {
        super(MergesortInversionCounter::count);
    }
}
```

**NaturalMergesortInversionCounterTest.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

/**
 * This unit test tests the correctness of the mergesort-based inversion 
 * counter.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 30, 2017)
 */
public class NaturalMergesortInversionCounterTest 
        extends AbstractInversionCounterTest {

    public NaturalMergesortInversionCounterTest() {
        super(NaturalMergesortInversionCounter::count);
    }
}
```

**MyBenchmark.java**

```
package net.coderodde;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import net.coderodde.util.MergesortInversionCounter;
import net.coderodde.util.NaturalMergesortInversionCounter;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Level;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

/**
 * This class implements benchmark for inversion counter algorithms.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 31, 2017)
 */
public class MyBenchmark {

    private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 1_000_000;
    private static final int MINIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE = -100_000;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE = +100_000;
    private static final int RUN_LENGTH_IN_PRESORTED_ARRAY = 2000;

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class MyRandomState {

        private final Random random = new Random();
        Integer[] array;

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void createRandomArray() {
            array = createRandomIntegerArray(ARRAY_LENGTH,
                                             MINIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE,
                                             MAXIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE, 
                                             random);
        }
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class MyPresortedState {
        private final Random random = new Random();
        Integer[] array;

        @Setup(Level.Trial)
        public void createPresortedArray() {
            array = createPresortedIntegerArray(ARRAY_LENGTH,
                                                MINIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE,
                                                MAXIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE,
                                                random);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark 
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime) 
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void testMergesortOnRandomArray(MyRandomState state) {
        MergesortInversionCounter.count(state.array);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime) 
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void testMergesortOnPresortedArray(MyPresortedState state) {
        MergesortInversionCounter.count(state.array);
    }

    @Benchmark 
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void testNaturalMergesortOnRandomArray(MyRandomState state) {
        NaturalMergesortInversionCounter.count(state.array);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void testNaturalMergesortOnPresortedArray(MyPresortedState state) {
        NaturalMergesortInversionCounter.count(state.array);
    }

    private static Integer[] createRandomIntegerArray(int length,
                                                      int minimumIntegerValue,
                                                      int maximumIntegerValue,
                                                      Random random) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            array[i] = getRandomIntegerValue(minimumIntegerValue,
                                             maximumIntegerValue,
                                             random);
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static Integer[] 
        createPresortedIntegerArray(int length,
                                    int minimumIntegerValue,
                                    int maximumIntegerValue,
                                    Random random) {
        Integer[] randomArray = createRandomIntegerArray(length,
                                                         minimumIntegerValue,
                                                         maximumIntegerValue,
                                                         random);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += RUN_LENGTH_IN_PRESORTED_ARRAY) {
            Arrays.sort(randomArray,
                        i, 
                        Math.min(length, i + RUN_LENGTH_IN_PRESORTED_ARRAY));
        }

        return randomArray;
    }

    private static Integer getRandomIntegerValue(int minimumIntegerValue,
                                                 int maximumIntegerValue,
                                                 Random random) {
        return minimumIntegerValue + random.nextInt(maximumIntegerValue -
                                                    minimumIntegerValue + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                          .include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                          .warmupIterations(5)
                          .measurementIterations(10)
                          .forks(1)
                          .build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }
}
```

## Benchmark figures

> ```
> Benchmark                                         Mode  Cnt    Score     Error  Units
> MyBenchmark.testMergesortOnPresortedArray         avgt   10  317.640 ± 187.535  ms/op
> MyBenchmark.testMergesortOnRandomArray            avgt   10  168.408 ±  37.833  ms/op
> MyBenchmark.testNaturalMergesortOnPresortedArray  avgt   10   39.191 ±  17.872  ms/op
> MyBenchmark.testNaturalMergesortOnRandomArray     avgt   10   50.237 ±  11.120  ms/op
> ```

## Info

The actual counters live [*here*](https://github.com/coderodde/InversionCounters). The benchmark lives [*here*](https://github.com/coderodde/inversion-counter-benchmark).

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind, be it related to algorithms, unit testing or benchmarking.

Comment: I don't see any *UnitTest* since the classes you named `*Test` do not verify anything accept that the called constructors do not fail...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I just checked it by inserting `fail()` into the abstract test. It gets called two times (once for each algo), so, yes, they are getting tested.

Comment: then you have a problem in your (Test-) class design. Since the behavior in each test is the same there should be only one test class using the different Sorter classes. A [parameterized Test](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) would have been appropriate...

Comment: @Timothy Truckle Looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Working for 1+ years in QA Blackbox/Whitebox team I would say that you must test every possible combination that could be in your code. 
 So you have check indexes util - ok, you need to have IndexesUtilTest
You check happy scenarios, you check unhappy scenarios. 
You will see [image]

Which means that you haven't covered some method. You might be sure about your code if you covered different scenarios. Even if you missed 20%, you will not start from scratch if you find some bug - you'll just add unit test, sample input and you're done.

If we take class for example:
    public final class Utils {

```
public static final Comparator NATURAL_ORDER = new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {            
        return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);    
    }
};

public static void checkIndices(int arrayLength,
                                int fromIndex, 
                                int toIndex) {
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") < 0");
    }

    if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                "toIndex(" + toIndex + ") > " + 
                "arrayLength(" + arrayLength + ")");
    }

    if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
    }
}
```

}

So for your comparator - you might have

```
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
```

null pointer exception if o1 == null.
so for comparator

```
test_o1_o2_not_null()
test_o1_null_o2_not_null(), etc
```

So go with coverage and all possible scenarios, name your tests nicely and you're fine!